# How to get object key from the api call dynamically and change the payload structure format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I store the following current array of objects into the object key and value pairs by using the key dynamically? I have another api that uses the same api call, but instead of using the keys **Desc** and **DSTR_NR**, it has different keys:

```
{
  list: [
    [
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7777 - Florida Hurricane'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7777'
        }
      },
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7172'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried to do the following but it didn't help:

```
const data = list.map((item) => {
  return {
    name: Object.values(item),
    value: Object.values(item)
  }
})
```

Desired format I want am looking for is this:

```
{
  list: [
    {
      name: '7777',
      value: '7777 - Florida Hurricane'
    },
    {
      name: '7172',
      value: '7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.values` gives an array of all the values of that object.

Also your list is an array of array so you have to flatten it first or if it just has one value use `list[0]`

An Example solution can be as below

```js
const data = {
  "list": [
    [{
      "Desc": {
        "value": "7777 - Florida Hurricane"
      },
      "DSTR_NR": {
        "value": "7777"
      }
    }, {
      "Desc": {
        "value": "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)"
      },
      "DSTR_NR": {
        "value": "7172"
      }
    }]
  ]
};


const newList = data.list.flat().map(item => ({
  name: item.DSTR_NR.value,
  value: item.Desc.value
}));

console.log({
  list: newList
})
```